# react state doesn't change in componentDidmount()

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am fetching data from firebase and try to console.log after retrieving it.
this is what i tried:

```
state = {
    users: null,
    usersRetrieved: false,
  };

getUsersList() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref('/users/')
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        let data = snapshot.val();
        this.setState({ users: data, usersRetrieved: true });
        console.log('users data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUsersList();
    this.state.usersRetrieved
      ? console.log('Users List: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.users))
      : null;
  }
```

This part prints out good console.log('users data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
But the console.log part in componentDidMount doesn't print out.
I know it's with sync/async thing. But how should i fix it, i am going to pass that users state to child components, where i made a mistake?

Muhammad Haseeb offer:

```
getUsersList() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref('/users/')
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        let data = snapshot.val();
        // this.setState({ users: data, usersRetrieved: true });
        // console.log('users data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        return data;
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let data = this.getUsersList();
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({ users: data, usersRetrieved: true });
    this.state.usersRetrieved
      ? console.log('Users List: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.users))
      : null;
  }
```

Comment: This is because setState work asynchronously and you will not get the updated state right after setting it.
I would recommend to return the data from your then and set it in the componentDidMount

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb I tried like u said, but I get data undefined, edited the question with your suggestion

Comment: What are you trying to do? just check the state? if so look at the react dev tools extension or log `this.state` inside render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't made any mistake (at least yet).

Because you are doing the server request inside `componentDidMount`, this means that the component will firstly render without any data. This means that when first rendering the component `this.state.usersRetrieved` will be `false` and `this.state.users` will be still `null`.

So, until this point you haven't done anything wrong. When the API request succeeds, `setState()` will be called and `users` won't be `null` anymore. This means your component will update and will have your real data.

What does this mean for you? You said you want to pass the `users` piece of state to a child component. Perfectly, just pass it. First time it will be `null`, but after the next update, your child component will also contain the non-null users data. You have to be careful about the fact that the first time your child component renders, it won't have any users, so you need to be careful to render accordingly (Your child component needs to know how to render itself when data exists, but also when data does not exist).